# ASPxClientDateEdit GetDate()

Tags: devexpress

I am using DevExpress v10. I have an ASPxDateEdit control on a web page. When a button on the form is clicked, my client-side JavaScript code needs to get value of the ASPxDateEdit control.
I used method ASPxClientDateEdit.GetDate() for this. 
But I have found the following problem: the GetDate() does NOT return current value in certain situations. Suppose I have some date in the ASPxDateEdit control. I clear the field (using keyboard) and click that my button immediately, not moving focus from the ASPxDateEdit control. In this situation the ASPxClientDateEdit.GetDate() call returns OLD value, despite the control's field is already empty.

How can my script retrieve exactly what is on the screen at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the client-side **ASPxClientDateEdit.GetText()** method and compare its result with the **ASPxClientDateEdit.GetDate()** value.

P.S. Why don't you contact the DX guys regarding your issues?

Comment: "Why don't you contact the DX guys regarding your issues?" - I post the questions to DX forum too. But they usually answer not earlier than week.

Comment: 'You can use the client-side ASPxClientDateEdit.GetText()' - I have tried the approach you proposed - it does not work, unfortunately. The ASPxClientDateEdit.GetText() returns OLD VALUE TOO.

The only workaround I have found to the moment is: to call ASPxClientDateEdit.Validate() BEFORE calling ASPxClientDateEdit.GetText()/GetDate()/GetValue(). This makes them returning the ACTUAL value.

But this workaround has its own downsides. 
Do you know any better solution?

Comment: These forums are peer-to-peer only. For your guaranteed official answer within 24 h, contact their Support Team at http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=question.